# InnerHTML not updating?

Tags: javascript, dom, shopify, liquid, shopify-api

Trying to load product recommendations into HTML, I can see the response is good and I am receiving the expected data but I'm not seeing any changes to the DOM. Most of this code was pulled from Shopify documentation, not sure what the problem is. All of this code is inside of a cart-drawer.liquid file

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var list = document.querySelector(".product-recommendations__list");
    console.log(list)
    // Get the base URL for translated product recommendations
    var baseUrl = list.dataset.baseUrl;
    console.log(baseUrl)
    // Get the product ID to request the product recommendations
    var productId = list.dataset.productId;
    console.log(productId)
    // Create an AJAX request
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open(
      "GET",
      baseUrl + ".json?product_id=" + productId + "&limit=4"
    );

    request.onload = function() {

      if (request.status === 404 || request.status === 422) {
        return hideRecommendationsSection();
      }

      var products = JSON.parse(request.response).products;

      if (products.length === 0) {
        return hideRecommendationsSection();
      }

      // Append product recommendations to the DOM.
      console.log(products)
      list.innerHTML = products.map(function(product) { return renderProduct(product) }).join("");
      console.log(list.innerHTML)
    };

    request.onerror = function() {
      hideRecommendationsSection();
    };

    // Send AJAX request
    request.send();

    function hideRecommendationsSection() {
      console.log('in hideRecommendations')
      list.style.display = "none";
    }

    function renderProduct(product) {
      return [
        '<div>',
        '<a href="' + product.url + '" class="product__anchor">',
        '<img class="product__img" src="' + product.featured_image + '" alt="'+ product.title +'"/>',
        '<p class="product__title">' + product.title + '</p>',
        '<p class="product__price">' + product.price + '</p>',
        '</a>',
        '</div>'
      ].join("");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product-recommendations__list" data-base-url="{{ routes.product_recommendations_url }}" data-product-id="{{ item.product_id }}"></div>
```

[image: Screenshot of the data being logged, as well as the innerHTML of the element right after the insertion of the HTML]

[image: Screenshot of the element]

Answer (score 0):

That list variable is a list of dom elements so try to loop first before changing the dom try this it might help

```
list.foreEach(domElement=>{
    domElement.innerHTML = products.map(function(product) { return renderProduct(product) }).join("")
 })
```